# Unhighlight Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, resharper

My code in visual studio has become highlighted, when I was testing how to comment a code selection with ctrl + K and ctrl + U

I didn't manage to comment the code but I got this strange behaviour. Here is an image:

[image]

How do I get rid of the code highlighting? I have Resharper and .Net Reflector.

The scope of the highlighting is my solution. Restarting VS does not fix it. Other solutions do not have highlighting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like dotCover's unit test coverage highlighting. You can disable it in the ReSharper menu: *Resharper > Cover > Toggle Code Highlighting*